# Android Notification How to change text near time?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to change the highlighted text in my notification. This is my package name but I'm not sure how to set the notification to show something else besides my package name? I'm using Xamarin for this.

[image]

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        var notification = builder.SetContentIntent(PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, 0))
                .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcNotificationOverlay)
                .SetContentTitle("myAdvantage")
                .SetContentText(message)
                .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification)) // set the sound
                .SetAutoCancel(true).Build();
```

Comment: Or, if anyone can tell me what the term is for that part of a notification, it would be a lot easier to search around..

Comment: You are using FCM for notifications?

Comment: @Yupi i'm using Azure Notification Hub which is using the key from FCM